# iText : How to redirect to a url after submitting a Pdf Form when it is displayed in an iframe?

Tags: java, redirect, iframe, itext, pdf-form

I have successfully managed to submit a Pdf form following the instructions given in the book (9.2.1 *Adding a submit button to an existing form*).

On submit a Java servlet is called:

```
submitButtonField.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(SERVLET_URL, null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT));
```

After processing the received data the servlet redirects to a specific url:

```
response.sendRedirect(REDIRECT_URL);
```

This works well when the Pdf is not displayed in an iframe.

My problem is that my Pdf is displayed in an iframe and only the iframe is redirected instead of the parent window.

A solution would be for my servlet to return the REDIRECT_URL and then call some javascript to redirect the parent window:

```
function redirectAfterFormSubmit(redirectUrl) {
    window.top.location.href = redirectUrl;
}
```

But I do not know how I could call this javascript function after the form has been submitted.

How can I do that with iText ?

EDIT:

I manage to call javascript after the submit by doing this:

```
String javascript = "function redirectAfterFormSubmit(redirectUrl) {window.top.location.href = redirectUrl;}";
pdfStamper.addJavaScript(javascript);

PdfAction action = PdfAction.createSubmitForm(SERVLET_URL, null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT);
action.next(PdfAction.javaScript(String.format("redirectAfterFormSubmit('%s')", REDIRECT_URL), pdfStamper.getWriter()));
```

But it is not working.
If I show the console I can see the error message:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Thanks for any help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this workaround that works well.
It's not very elegant but I cannot find another solution.
If someone has a more elegant solution, feel free to post.

Instead of calling `response.sendRedirect` in my servlet:

```
response.sendRedirect(REDIRECT_URL);
```

I write to the response an html page containing the call the the redirect in javascript:

```
String redirectPage = "<script language=javascript>\n" + 
                    "function redirect(){\n" + 
                    "  window.top.location.href = \"" + redirectUrl + "\";\n" + 
                    "}\n" + 
                    "</script>\n" + 
                    "\n" + 
                    "<body onload=\"redirect()\">\n" + 
                    "\n" + 
                    "</body>";

response.getWriter().println(redirectPage);
```